# Azure Mobile Service SQL Database Connection

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure mobile service which has a sql database. I would like to get a connection between my windows phone app and azure mobile service sql database. How can I achieve it?

In TodoItem example, there is no any table information that data will be taken.

P.S. : Googled a lot but nothing satisfied even azure documentation. TodoItem example does not show some details. For example my database table name is `Scores` where code line should I edit in TodoItem example?

You can download TodoItem example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Add-Azure-Mobile-to-a-8b906f72).

Comment: Ill be honest, I know nothing about MobileServices. But [this link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/) appears to be helpful. You should be able to access your data through `Client.GetTable` I think.

Comment: I just want to full customize TodoItem example with mines (my database structure also fully different)

Answer (score 1):

in Azure Mobile Service, you don't access the database directly from your mobile application. you talk to the Mobile Service backend which in turn talks to your database.

as @hSchroedl mentioned, you should use the Mobile Service API to access your database tables.

You can easily follow the TodoItem sample to create representations of your own tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how do I get my Azure Mobile services database connection string, then the answer is: look in the Azure portal -> your Mobile Services name -> Dashboard tab -> Click on your database name. There you have your database connection string.

You can use this connection string in Visual Studio to connect to your Mobile Services database but can't be used directly in your mobile app.

**Note**: You can't access your database directly from your mobile app without using the Azure Mobile Services APIs.

Take a moment and review the [Azure Mobile services documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/) and tutorials to get a better understanding of it works.

Hope this helps